# A word for someone who sees problems but not solutions

Tags: single-word-requests

At work, a nurse approached me with a medical gadget with a sticky-note attached that said "Needs New Batteries". She pointed out that it would have been quicker to go to the cupboard, find batteries and replace them than to walk to the office for a note and write it out. She wanted to know the word for someone who would do that.

So what do we call someone who would rather point out a problem than find a solution? Or what would we call that way of thinking?

Comment: pessimist. cynic. critic.

Comment: Captain Hindsight comes to mind...

Comment: To answer that we need to know *why* the person chose to do it that way.  Was it because they were too lazy? Was it because they didn't want to  be taken for granted and become the person who always changes the batteries?  Was it because they didn't have time to change the batteries right then, but wanted to let the next person know that this one wasn't working and save them a second trip? Etc.

Comment: There is an attitude called "not in my job description".  This might be the reason why the person wrote the note instead of installing the battery.   (Or the person who scrawled the note might have been on her way to a very sick patient.)

Comment: I think you can get a sense by the comments and answers which are kinda all over the place, we'd really need to know the motive of the note-leaver to accurately peg the characteristic(s) of the person.

Comment: I think you need another, and unambiguous, example.  Do you mean someone who finds a problem with every solution, but whose criticisms are never constructive, and who never offers a solution of her own?  If so, "nay-sayer." Or do you mean someone who is just hands a problem off to someone else: "Here, problem, you fix it."   If so, "lazy" or maybe "stupid."

Comment: @Drew I was being sloppy -- what I meant was someone who habitually hands a problem off to someone else.  As I said in an earlier comment, In the example the OP gave, the hander-off could have been rushing to help a very sick patient.

Comment: _Delegator_ might be an apt term, although it tends to imply someone who is higher up in the organization than the person to whom he or she leaves the actual task that is in need of doing.

Answer (score 1):

The closest term I know for that is "buck-passer".
Instead of participating in fixing the problem, they "pass the buck".

"Our city mayor is a professional buck-passer.  He gave a two speeches last month complaining about the dire city budget situation, but our city treasurer tells me the mayor has repeatedly refused her meeting requests to review budget options."

The word "naysayer" could apply to someone who points out all the reasons why something can't or shouldn't be done, and supplies no solution.  However, that's not fit for this situation, because the person actually took action, though it was a thoughtless, wasteful action.  Buck-passer is a better fit because the person DID take action, but their action had the effect of passing the buck, of making someone else responsible for the solution.

Comment: The free dictionary idioms area also shows the unhyphenated version, "buckpasser".  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buckpasser

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a **do-nothing moralizer**

"moralize" definition : to reflect on or express opinions about something in terms of right and wrong, especially in a self-righteous or tiresome way.

Answer (score 0):

A **downer** is someone who points out all the flaws in anything, and creates a negative atmosphere around anything.

**Passive-aggressive** is another way to describe the type of behavior displayed by the person who left the note.

Comment: I thought we were looking for the word for the person who left the device with the note, not the nurse who found it.

Comment: @Barmar i misread the paragraph.  I'm editing my answer acordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it quite matches your title but it certainly seems to fit your requirements. A *[jobsworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jobsworth)* is a person who finds that

> taking the initiative and performing an action, and perhaps in the
>   process breaking a rule, is beyond what the person feels their job
>   description allows

Such individuals are notorious for *[malicious compliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malicious_compliance)*:-

> Malicious compliance is the behavior of a person who intentionally
>   inflicts harm by strictly following the orders of management or
>   following legal compulsions, knowing that compliance with the orders
>   will cause a loss of some form

when their behaviour cannot be explained by idleness.

Comment: Ooh, I like malicious compliance. I'm going to save it in my phrase book.

Answer (score 0):

*Requirements analyst* - specifies what's needed.  Describes the "what", and generally not the "how".

Describes a **problem**.  Does not (as a requirements analyst) design or implement a **solution**. (Those are activities done by designers and implementors.)

There is nothing inherently pessimistic, debbie-downerish, cynical, passive-aggressive, do-nothing, or lazy about specifying a problem.

We need more talented and careful requirements analysts.  Get the problem right and you have a much better chance of getting the right solution.  (Think - problem specified as Sadam having weapons of mass destruction; solution produced: Iraq War... Bad spec.)

Answer (score -1):

Back Seat Driver -they dont want the responsibility of driving the process, they only want the authority. Good managers know - responsibilities come with authority, you cant have authority without responsibility.